# How to remove all non-alphanumerical characters except when part of a word

Tags: python, regex

Given the following multiline string:

```
One, 123
three 'four'    can't
```

I need to end up with:

```
One 123 three four can't
```

In short; I want to match all non-letters and non-numbers except the apostrophe in `can't`

Using `(?<=[a-z])'(?=[a-z])` I get a match on the apostrophe in `can't`, and can therefore just negate it(?)

Using `[^a-z0-9]+` I get a match on all the characters I in the end just want to replace with a simple space, but this also matches the apostrophe in `can't`.

How can I achieve both goals; match all non-numeric characters, except the apostrophes that's part of a word?

P.S. I'm using Python to do this

Comment: Any chance of `'`s coming at the end? Consider, eg `games'` - that's a legitimate word

Comment: Use `r"(?!\b'\b)'"`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ICpSN/1). Or a more precise (as you want to match `'` not inside letters only) `r"'(?!(?<=[a-zA-Z]')[a-zA-Z])"`

Comment: Thx for helping! Wiktor's solution worked perfectly.